# Read file and insert delimiter in output file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, delimiter, delimited

I've found the following code from @Kieranties that works really well for me except my input file does not contain a date in the first row.

The output file does not input the date (that's ok) nor does it input the pipe delimiter in the first row.  All other rows are perfect.

I tried to modify this code with no luck.

```
Function Parse-CDRFileLine {
    Param(
        [string]$line
    )

    $pattern = "^(.{2})(.{2})(.{1})(.{2})(.{1})(.{1})\s*(.{15})(.{10})\s*(.{7})\s*(.{7})\s*(.{1})\s*(.{1})(.{1})(.{1})\s*(.*)$"
    if($line -match $pattern){ 
        $result = $matches.Values | select -first ($matches.Count-1)
        [array]::Reverse($result, 0, $result.Length)
        $result = $result -join "|"    
        $result
    }
}



Function Parse-CDRFile{
    Param(
        [string]$filepath
    )    

    # Read content, setting first line to $date, the rest to $content
    $date,$content = Get-Content $filepath    

    # Create the output file, overwrite if neccessary
    $outputFile = New-Item "$filepath.out" -ItemType file -Force

    # Add the date line
    Set-Content $outputFile $date

    # Process the rest of the content
    $content | 
        ? { -not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)) } |
        % { Add-Content $outputFile (Parse-CDRFileLine $_) }
}

Parse-CDRFile "C:\input.txt"
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or as close as you can get to one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.  I had to remove the "$date," from the line that read $date,$content = Get-Content $filepath and completely remove the line. Set-Content $outputFile $date

Final code is.

```
Function Parse-CDRFileLine {
    Param(
        [string]$line
    )

    $pattern = "^(.{2})(.{2})(.{1})(.{2})(.{1})(.{1})\s*(.{15})(.{10})\s*(.{7})\s*(.{7})\s*(.{1})\s*(.{1})(.{1})(.{1})\s*(.*)$"
    if($line -match $pattern){ 
        $result = $matches.Values | select -first ($matches.Count-1)
        [array]::Reverse($result, 0, $result.Length)
        $result = $result -join "|"    
        $result
    }
}



Function Parse-CDRFile{
    Param(
        [string]$filepath
    )    

    # Read content, setting first line to $date, the rest to $content
    $content = Get-Content $filepath    

    # Create the output file, overwrite if neccessary
    $outputFile = New-Item "$filepath.out" -ItemType file -Force


    # Process the rest of the content
    $content | 
        Where { -not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)) } |
        Foreach { Add-Content $outputFile (Parse-CDRFileLine $_) }
}

Parse-CDRFile "C:\input.txt"
```